# How to get the google domain of user?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to know if it's possible to get the google domain a user belongs to or the domain of the groups a user belongs to. I don't know if this is possible does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
user.getAuthDomain()
```

See: Class User in [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User#getAuthDomain%28%29) or in [PHP](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/files/google.appengine.api.users.User#%5Cgoogle%5Cappengine%5Capi%5Cusers%5CUser)

Comment: That code line might work, but there's not even link to official documentation / API reference. Following that logic just 'Yes' as  answer to authors question 'if this is possible' would be enough.

Comment: @sandstar: I added a link to satisfy you. Click on it to see how much value you have added.

Comment: Sorry I should have said this is a php app. Is there a php equivalent?

Comment: Same. I added a link.